# The margin on my cssmodules file doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, css-modules

I'm doing a create-react-app project and there is a weird situation here.

I'm importing like this:

```
import styles from './UserLoginModal.module.css';
```

Applying in like this:

```
const errorMessage = <Typography variant='h5' className={styles.errorMessage}>Ocurrio un error al iniciar sesión: {error}</Typography>
```

And my .css file looks like this:

```
.errorMessage {
   margin-top: 1rem;
   text-align: center;
   color: red;
}
```

My text-align and the red color are working, but the margin doesn't!! If I use the margin with inline style it works properly:

```
style={{marginTop: 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a style overwriting the margin style from your css file .
You may want to use ***!important*** with your style :

```
.errorMessage {
   margin-top: 1rem !important;
   text-align: center;
   color: red;
}
```

To find out the style overwriting your css styles , you can inspect the element with browser developer tools and check which styles apply to the element .